# Hydration error on login using Next-Auth in NextJS 13.4

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth, hydration

## How to reproduce ?

`'node -v' -> v18.16.1`

`'npx -v' -> 9.8.0`

I created a nextjs app using `npx create-next-app@latest` using the app folder

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrUQD.png)

Next i installed Next Auth using `npm i next-auth`

[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5d3V.png)

This is a standard next auth route:

```
import { authOptions } from "@/app/options/authOptions";
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

I created my custom session provider to be client rendered like youtube tutorials:

```
"use client";

import React from "react";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";

interface Props {
    children?: React.ReactNode;
}

export default function NextAuthSessionProvider({ children }: Props) {
    return (
        <SessionProvider>
            { children }
        </SessionProvider>
    )
}
```

My auth options:

```
interface User {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    email: string;
}

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req): Promise<User | null> {
        if (credentials?.username === "a" && credentials?.password === "b") {
          return { id: "1", name: "John Smith", email: "john@example.com" };
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }
    })
  ]
}
```

My layout wrapping the content:

```
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <NextAuthSessionProvider>{children}</NextAuthSessionProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

My Home Page:

```
import Link from 'next/link';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <Link href={'/dashboard'}>
        Dashboard
      </Link>
      <br />
      <Link href={'/api/auth/signin'}>
        Sign in
      </Link>
      <br />
      <Link href={'/api/auth/signout'}>
        Sign out
      </Link>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And this is my session protected dashboard page:

```
export default async function DashboardPage() {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

  if (!session) {
    redirect('/api/auth/signin');
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Dashboard</h1>
      <p>
        This page is only accessible to signed-in users.
      </p>
      <Link href={'/'}>
        Home
      </Link>
      <br />
      <Link href={'/api/auth/signout'}>
        Sign out
      </Link>
    </div>
  )
}
```

## The error

When i'm on the home page and i click on Dashboard, i'm redirected to `/api/auth/signin`, then i can fill the signin form using `username: a, password: b`

Then when i sign in i'm redirected to `url: /` not `url: /dashboard` dont know why but okay and it display me 3 errors :
[error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W53J4.png)

[error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cp6dI.png)

[error 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o53oA.png)

I checked many youtube tutorials or tried to search in documentation but i cant find anything about that :/

I checked many youtube tutorials or tried to search in documentation but i cant find anything about that :/

Comment: I have the same issue when i use `getServerSession()`

Answer (score 1):

I spend last few hours trying to debug the same issue. It was by Bitwarden extension that seems to inject some HTML on the page causing these errors... Adding "localhost" from excluded domains in Bitwarden config resolved the issue.